# How to copy MongoDB database from server to local machine?

Tags: mongodb

I need to **dump database** on to the folder on the server and then **scp** it to local machine. I tried the below methods:

`mongodump --ssl -u root -p password --authenticationDatabase name -d databaseName -o /database`

Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

`mongodump -u root -p password --authenticationDatabase name -d databaseName -o /database`

Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.

```
tried to do --host=ip.ad.re.ss:27017
tried to do --host=host-name:27017
            --host=127.0.0.1:27017
            --host=web-address:27017
```

Tried to switch off mongodb and copy files manually, but end up with the empty database on the local machine.

I also tried to use:

`mongo --> db.copydatabase(from, to, name)`

How to use mongodump? Possible to use any other way. Only through terminal, ubuntu setup doesn't have any gnu.

Comment: I created admin with root privileges, and using this authentication to copy database. But it still gives me auth error... I tried to show users... it gives me empty array, but if I use admin, then show users it gives me admin... Totally confused how to use mongodump.

Comment: Do you mean how to copy the entire Mongo database? You can simply copy the `dbPath` folder (stop the database before you copy it). If you got an empty database then most likely you set `dbPath` wrong at your local machine.

Comment: I tried  to scp them, but as I remember right now, at that operation I didn't stop mongo. May be because of this my dbs on the local machine is empty? After that I started trying to mongodump... aaaaannd it's just doesn't work for me :( I have no idea why... I will try to scp tomorrow. I hope you are right. I was fighting with mongo for many many hours today...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you said - more errorless method:

- connect to server and create dump there (like this,
  `mongodump -u root -p password --authenticationDatabase admin -d databaseName -o /database`)
- scp database dump from the server to vm
- Restore DB on VM
  `mongorestore --authenticationDatabase=admin -u=root -p=password ./dump/`

Based on your error:

- you are doing something wrong in params (did you use `--authenticationDatabase admin`)?
- you are doing something wrong with regarding place (server, network)

Basically, your variant should work, just need to adjust the params for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it. I just saw your answer. Have a great day!

Comment: I will try scp with switched off database first... Because this mongodump command I tried many variations with it, but it's fighting with me... I tried admin and plus created admin and tried with new admin with root privileges... One time I had not authenticated with admin user :))

Comment: Hello. Your answer was the closest to the right answer. Could you please fix your answer accordingly so I can give it a check mark. "My approach was too complicated to save database from the server to the vm on the local comp. As I understand the host ip could not be recognised inside of the vm, so no way this copying could be done in one step. So what I did: 1. mongodump -d (or --db?) databaseName (on the server) 2. scp database dump from the server to vm 3. mongorestore --verbose \path\from ...

Comment: Obviously there is a way to mongodump from server to server, But this question would be usefull for people who get confused trying to copy database from a server to vm...

Comment: I didn't actually know that this command can be used separately to dump and restore. That's why I didn't think right away to separate this command into 3 smaller steps... I have no idea who and why gave you - mark, you were very close to complete right answer... no authentication required though with the command, no ssl when copying to the same server... the commands are actually short and simple.

Comment: Though I'm facing the other problem, somehow after copying the datato vm and to other server. Images which are in a database cannot be seeing on the site. I looked through them and it seems somehow different ip address screwing mongodb database. I never delt with MongoDB untill now, always worked with PostgreSQL. Think PostgreSQL is far best database out there. Although had issues with CPanel , to the point when started to use only psql to communicate with the database.

Comment: @bugthefifth Hello, i don't know what exactly i need to fix in my answer? i think it covers the same as you did, what I am missing?

Comment: @bugthefifth about issue with images, to be honest, I didn't get what is wrong there:(

Comment: "1st step:  mongodump -d (or --db?) databaseName (to a server) 2nd step:  scp database dump from the server to vm 3rd step: mongorestore --verbose \path\from ... Commands might be not exact, p[lease look into the documentation for Mongodb"

Comment: @bugthefifth I edited it. Maybe will be helpful for someone else

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is missing from your mongodump command is... "" round your --host -value.

```
--host="host-name:27017"
```

Check similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289092/mongodump-failing-to-connection-replica-set/289154#289154)

Comment: Hello! TY for replying. I tried this: /usr/bin/mongodump --host="https://www.webAdress.com:27017" --ssl -u root -p password --authenticationDatabase admin -d databaseName -o /database

Comment: error dialing 127.0.0.1:27017: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused

Comment: error dialing host-forDatabase:27017: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused

Comment: When use this command with the web address: Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Comment: I know the port is right. I checked it through mongo. I tried all possible variations of connection... Still it says it cannot connect or refuse to connect.

Comment: /usr/bin/mongodump -h "ip | web " -u "root" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase admin -d tm4rent -o /database. Received this error:                                              Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: ip:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp ip:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }

Comment: Can you connect to that mongod process with mongo -command? Is mongod running? (pgrep mongod) If process is running, what is bindIP value i.e. what IP address mongod process is listening.

Comment: Oh, now I noticed one thing... When you use the parameter '--authenticationDatabase' "right" value is ALWAYS 'admin'

Comment: Yes mongo works and all of its commands. It appears that the version 4.4 has a different version of going through this process of copying database. At least I was told so today and it appears that a different version of mongo has a different versions of this command. I have to look through docs. The same person advised me to copy full server to the vm, and so this way I won't have any troubles with compatibility of different programs. I cannot find any plausible info about how to do it . :)) Only server to server copying...